# Issues with the dual VNH2SP30 motor carrier and 131:1 metal gearmotor 37Dx73L mm w/ 64 cpr encoders

Tags: mobile-robot, motor, electronics, circuit, driver

For a while now I have been trying to build my own robotic platform, kind of like a turtlebot. However, I have kept running into an issue with controlling the motors. My main controller for sensor data input and motor driving output is the tiva c TM4C123G launchpad, which operates at 3.3V so I shift the signals to 5V (which the motor driver operates on).

The motor driver seems to respond correctly when the actual motor is not attached, but the LEDs that indicate the ouput do not shine when the motor is plugged in.

Here is a video which explains my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-Da2iAS8L8

I have tried using an arduino mega instead of the launchpad, but unfortunately the 64 CPR encoders are too fast for the mega to read and I need the encoder data (I'm trying to perform SLAM).

I honestly have no idea what is wrong with my circuit/boards I appreciate any help or insight on this problem! Thank you!

Since I'm also a high schooler I unfortunately do not have access to nicer tools such as oscilloscopes...